# PHP CURL Check if file exist on URL

Tags: php, curl

i have the following Code for check if file exist on server before download.

```
function is_url_exist($url){
    $username="user"; 
    $password= "pass";
    $ch = curl_init($url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    print_r($code);
    if($code == 200){
       $status = true;
    }else{
      $status = false;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
   return $status;
}

$url="https://example.com/datafeed/getReport?filename=report-20161101.tsv.gz";

$t=is_url_exist($url);

print($t);
```

Print($code) output is: 500. I'm sure that file exists. Any Ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: just add this and check :curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Comment: Download URL is not proper when I try to open it gives me 500 error.  
https://example.com/datafeed/getReport?filename=report-20161101.tsv.gz

Comment: i think he changed the original url and posted

Comment: @lalithkumar: still 500

Comment: @AnantWaykar: Yes, its not the original url.

Comment: if you are executing the original url in chrome the file is downloading? @swapfile

Comment: @lalithkumar: Yes, download starts automatic

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
```

This was missing. With that its working!